# Best signal processing method for recognising changes in accelerometer results?

Tags: signal-analysis, imu

I am new to signal processing and trying to build a gadget that hits an object and recognizes fractures and weaknesses in it using an accelerometer attached to a hammer. I have some initial results from manual tests and produced the waveforms below. The green wave is from a spot in the object that I know is intact. The blue wave has a fracture. The length of the big wave starting just before 0ms shows the contact time between the hammer and the object. It seems that if the object has a fracture, the contact time will be longer.

(The green wave is higher because I'm not hitting the object with a steady force just yet, but manually. In the final gadget, the height of the waves ought to be the same)

What kind of signal processing method could I use to compare the waves to recognize the fractures? Thank you!

[image: two wave signals showing contact time between hammer and object]

Answer (score 2):

Typically the best way to go about this types of problem is to start with a an analytic model that's based on the underlying physics and can predict (to some degree) what the responses would look like for a variety of failure modes. The can you design an algorithm that looks specifically for the response changes for each of the failure modes.

If you want to do this heuristically, you would have to start with a fairly large date collection that covers the majority of the use cases for your application and the relevant requirements (accuracy, distribution, noise-sensitivit, tolerance, etc.)

Once you have a decent set of data, you can try different analysis methods (time, frequency, cepstrum, feature extraction, etc) and see which one does the best job. That typically starts with "staring at the data": if you can see the difference, you can typically teach a computer to look for the same time of differences.

If that doesn't work out, you may need to look at machine learning, but this may require even larger data sets.

Comment: you need to have 'intact' responses recorded across a grid of points knowing that all points are ok. Then try damaged samples and make sure that you can tell intact from damaged, on each grid point. Once you can tell when a given point sounds ok or damaged you try uknown status samples, measure and verify measurement corresponds with actual status. Set up a percentage of acceptance, let's say 95% points predicted correctly then your system works, otherwise you have to make sure ok signals can be discerned from signals returning from damaged points.

Comment: This sort of thing is _probably_ going to show up better in the frequency domain -- i.e., a blow to an unbroken object will "sound like" a "ping" while a blow to a broken object will "sound like" a "thud", with lower high-frequency content.  But -- analysis or experiment is still your first step.

Comment: @TimWescott why_not_both.gif